# WCF Async Service or MVC Async controller thread usage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asynchronous, thread-safety

Can anyone explain when to use async controller versus an async wcf service? As in thread usage etc?
My async controller looks like this

```
 public class EventController : AsyncController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void RecordAsync(EventData eventData)
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        Debug.WriteLine("****** Writing to database -- n:{0} l:{1} ******", eventData.Name, eventData.Location);
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["eventData"] = eventData;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        }).Start();
    }

    public ActionResult RecordCompleted(EventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("****** Complete -- n:{0} l:{1} ******", eventData.Name, eventData.Location);
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

vs my WCF Service

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = ServiceConstants.Namespace)]
public class EventCaptureService: IEventCaptureService
{
    public EventCaptureInfo EventCaptureInfo { get; set; }

    public IAsyncResult BeginAddEventInfo(EventCaptureInfo eventInfo, AsyncCallback wcfCallback, object asyncState)
    {
        this.EventCaptureInfo = eventInfo;
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(this.PersistEventInfo, asyncState);
        return task.ContinueWith(res => wcfCallback(task));
    }

    public void EndAddEventInfo(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Task Completed");
    }

    private void PersistEventInfo(object state)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Foo:{0}", new object[]{ EventCaptureInfo.Foo});
    }

}
```

Notice the WCF Service uses Task whereas the Controller uses Thread.  I know little about threads and how they work.  I was just wondering which of these would be more effecient and not bomb my server.  The overall goal is to capture some activity in a Web App and call either the controller or the service (either of which will be on a different domain) and which is a better approach is better. Which is truly async? Do they use the same threads? Any help, tips, tricks, links etc... is always appreciated. My basic question is Async WCF Service or Async MVC Controller?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no "vs" in this case. Both have very similar purpose but at different context. Idea for both is to free and return current thread back to managed thread pool until some async operation completes. It is important to note that async operation does not mean start new thread, but something like I/O operation. So it is good practice to invoke WCF service from ASP.MVC using async controller and async method on client side. And for WCF service if you have DB call you can do that asynchronously and break service call around it.